# Can I get rid of my App canvas page? Redirect to website instead?

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-opengraph

I was wondering if there's a way to get rid of a Facebook apps canvas page?

Our open graph shares always link to the canvas page, where as Facebook apps like Pinterest and Soundcloud are able to link straight to their website instead of the app within Facebook.

Could anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Cheers,

Laurel

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your canvas app by going to your Fb app settings:

- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
- Click on Edit Settings in the settings box.
- Delete the Canvas URL links in the "App on Facebook" section.
- Click the Save Changes button at the bottom of the page.

Open Graph objects link to the URL specified in their own og:url metadata. For example, this is the metadata of a Pin object on Pinterest:

That url is the link target when you click on an Open Graph story.